# How to convert array of byte into pdf?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am using a web service which returns me array of bytes and i am trying to convert it into pdf but finding some difficulties .

Returned bytes are more than thousand lines so i can not paste all but this is how it starts

```
%PDF-1.2 
%âãÏÓ 
1 0 obj 
<< 
/Type /Catalog 
/Pages 2 0 R 
/PageMode /UseNone 
/ViewerPreferences << 
/FitWindow true 
/PageLayout /SinglePage 
/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone 
>> 
>> 
endobj 
5 0 obj 
<< 
/Length 1683 
/Filter [ /FlateDecode ] 
>> 
stream
xX[SâH~Ï¯èª}Á©Bú´oH2Ê®8ÎTYµ!jV...
```

I tried few solutions like

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.pdf"');
echo hex2bin($byte_string);
```

or

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.pdf"');
echo base64_decode($byte_string);
```

Comment: file_put_contents('file.pdf',$data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your response in varriable , like in $data
and if you are working in core php just write

```
file_put_contents('your_pdf_name.pdf',$data);
```

and if you are doing in laravel

```
file_put_contents(public_path('your_folder_name/your_pdf_name.pdf'),$data);
```

Comment: @BlackXero already answered it , it worked , any way thank you too